# Setting content header for file download in Nitrogen webserver

Tags: erlang, yaws, nitrogen

I am dynamically generating a file on Nitrogen Webserver and want the browser to show the name of file in download dialog.

Currently I am setting something like this -

```
wf:content_type("application/x-download")
```

This enables the browser to ask for saving the file, but the name of the file is name of the url (which is nitrogen erl page).

How can I set name of file on the content so that browser displays the same filename to user?

I think something like this can be acheived in a Java based server like this -

```
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fName + "\"");
```

I'm using Nitrogen on top of yaws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically almost there:

`wf:header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" ++ Filename ++ "\""),`